# QT 5 QPrinter linq error

Tags: qt5, qprinter

I use QT 5.1.1 and Qt Creator 2.8.1
I want use printer:

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    QPrintDialog printdialog(&printer,this);

    if (printdialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
    {
        QTextDocument doc;
        doc.setHtml(s);
        doc.print(&printer);
    }
```

And I get this error:

> DictionaryWidget.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: _*thiscall QPrinter::QPrinter(enum QPrinter::PrinterMode)" (*_imp_??0QPrinter@@QAE@W4PrinterMode@0@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall DictionaryWidget::on_pbPrint_clicked(void)" (?on_pbPrint_clicked@DictionaryWidget@@AAEXXZ)

in .pro file I have:

```
QT       += core gui xml printsupport
```

to build Environment in QT Creator LIBPATH as follows:

```
libpath: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framewo‌​rk64\v3.5;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\11.0\References\CommonConfigura‌​tion\neutral;C:\Qt\5.1.1\msvc2012\lib;
```

In the folder C:\Qt\5.1.1\msvc2012\lib file is located Qt5PrintSupport.lib

What should I do to make the project work?

Comment: Does your program has a class 'DictionaryWidget'?

Comment: If you change it in three places, it might work. If not... don't show us the printer stuff. The code, which causes the error is much more interesting.

Comment: I create new project QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

Form with one button#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrintDialog>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);  

} and have same error

Comment: Do you have the libQt5PrintSupport.so.5.1.1 lib in your Qt5 lib folder?

Comment: Are you aware, that you can edit your original post? Please do it. It is absolutely no fun to read these text blobs in comments. Extremely unlikely, that anyone reads through them and offers any help.

Comment: I changed the original post. Removed the comments that they do not interfere

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but if your .pro file really looks like this, it is wrong. It is LIBPATH += path_to_folder_with_libs. Not libpath:... So it probably should look like: LIBPATH += C:\Qt\5.1.1\msvc2012\lib. But I doubt this really is the problem. If all the other Qt libs are found, I don't know a reason why just the print support lib should not be found.

Comment: I'm sorry, again brought you a misleading way is not in the pro file, and in setting QT Creator

Comment: You have the .lib file. Do you also have the Qt5PrintSupport.dll? In search path? From what I can see here, I am at an end. No more ideas, why the linker does not find your lib. Maybe a lib on which the Qt5PrintSupport lib depends is missing. Maybe the dependency walker can help you there.

Comment: Greenflow, thank you very much for your help.Reinstalled qt, knocked on the tambourine and working. That was never realized. How to mark a question solved, or something like that?